# Smtp can't send mail Message get successful but mail not getting?

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, emails, smtp

I havn't get mail but message comes succesfully. please help me from smtp. And also i have use in HTMl mailing in template.

Answer (score 1):

If Joomla receives a code associated with a successful delivery, then it was delivered.

If it does not reach the target, then there is something wrong in mailing configuration.